# Fire a Child LWC Method From Parent LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, child-to-parent

**PARENT COMPONENT**

**parent.html**

```
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Select" title="Select Family"
data-id={fam.accountId} onclick={handleSelectFamily}
class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

**parent.Js**

```
handleSelectFamily(event)
{
    this.accountId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    alert('if');
    this.template.querySelector("c-transaction-Invoice-Payment").handlePayments();           
    alert('end');
}
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

**TransactionInvoicePayment.Js**

```
@api handlePayments() {
    console.log('IN handlePayments');
}
```

Trying to pass and trigger the child method from the parent LWC, but it doesn't trigger. Tried by doing alert only the first alert is prompting, Checked in console log too no error occurs.

Can you please help me with what I am missing here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the most likely source of error is your capitalization in the `querySelector`.

You have `this.template.querySelector("c-transaction-Invoice-Payment").handlePayments();`

But I suspect it's more likely to be:

`this.template.querySelector("c-transaction-invoice-payment").handlePayments();`

Comment: tried `this.template.querySelector("c-transaction-invoice-payment").handlePayments(this.accountId, this.transactionId);` still no luck

Comment: Can you put the html markup showing the parent compoent and the child component up? Another way you can query for the component is to put a css class on it and query for that. Also, you don't happen to be using a namespace do you?